# AngularJS Directive fire on multiple objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a custom directive that appends elements to specific portions of the DOM depending on the screen size. The function should fire on `$window.onresize` & `$window.onload`

The issue I'm having is getting the same directive to fire multiple times within a single view.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wfuller/vjd15m72/)

Where I'm getting lost is how to compile the directive for each element on the page.

HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div appendy appendy-from="#right1" appendy-to="#left1" appendy-breakpoint="768">
         <h3>Should move Left1 to Right1 OR Right1 to Left1</h3>
    </div>
    <div appendy appendy-from="#right2" appendy-to="#left2" appendy-breakpoint="768">
         <h3>Should move Left2 to Right2 OR Right2 to Left2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 text-center">
                 <h1>Left 1</h1>

                <div id="left1"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 text-center">
                 <h1>Right 1</h1>

                <div id="right1"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 text-center">
                 <h1>Left 2</h1>
                <div id="left2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 text-center">
                 <h1>Right 2</h1>
                <div id="right2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {}]);
app.directive('appendy', function ($window) {
return {
    restirct: 'AE',
    replace: 'false',
    template: '',
    link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
        var appendy = function () {
            scope.appendFrom = attributes["appendyFrom"];
            scope.appendTo = attributes["appendyTo"];
            scope.breakPoint = attributes["appendyBreakpoint"];

            var appendFrom = angular.element(document.querySelector(scope.appendFrom));
            var appendTo = angular.element(document.querySelector(scope.appendTo));
            var breakPoint = scope.breakPoint;
            var clientWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

            if (clientWidth < breakPoint) {
                appendFrom.append(element);
            } else {
                appendTo.append(element);
            }
        };

        $window.onresize = function () {
            appendy();
        };

        $window.onload = function () {
            appendy();
        };
    }
};
});
```

In looking at other code should the `appendy` function be attached to the scope than fired on the element when the $window is resized or loaded?

```
scope.appendy = function(){
//...
//...
}

element.($window).bind('resize, load', function(){
    scope.appendy();
})
```

Comment: hope you realize that `resize` occurs many times a second during manual resizing and that appending elements that are already in the place you want them to be causes a lot of expensive dom manipulation

Comment: beyond that really not clear what your problem is

Comment: I fully understand that `resize` occurs many times during manual resizing. I'm not worried about performance at this point and optimization comes later. I'm trying to understand how to isolate the directives to execute the same function. The problem is pretty clear in looking at the Fiddle. I have 2 directives in the view. Only 1 is working, I'm trying to get each directive to fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bind any of this to scope since parent scope is inherited by both instances and use `angular.element($window)`:

```
        var appendy = function () {
            var appendFrom = attributes["appendyFrom"];
            var appendTo = attributes["appendyTo"];
            var breakPoint = attributes["appendyBreakpoint"];

            appendFrom = angular.element(document.querySelector(appendFrom));
            appendTo = angular.element(document.querySelector(appendTo));

            var clientWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

            if (clientWidth < breakPoint) {
                appendFrom.append(element);
            } else {
                appendTo.append(element);
            }
        };

        angular.element($window).bind('resize load', appendy);

    }
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vjd15m72/4/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the scoping issue. Been having some issues understanding the whole scope of objects still very green at Angular. [update](https://jsfiddle.net/wfuller/vjd15m72/8/)